# Maven 3 antrun issue

Tags: maven, ant, build-process, maven-3, maven-plugin

Recentely we upgraded from maven2 to maven 3 but ant build are not working. Ant is not compiling my project in maven 3 but am able to compile the same project using maven 2.
For just a simple example i put some message to echo in my pom file
Am getting the message using maven 2.0.6 but whaen am using maveb 3.0.3
to run the same am not getting the message . 
Is there any compatiblity issue in ant and maven 3 ?
Am having following in my pom file

...

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
            <id>1</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <echo message="SOME MESSAGE TO DISPLAY " />
            </tasks>

        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: You link the execution to the "validate" phase, is this correct?

Comment: I try this with maven 2.2.1 and maven 3.0.4. And it works. Did you run 'mvn verify' ? Can you provide the full pom ?

Comment: thanx gontard , it also worked for me when i created a new project and tried it out o mavne 3.0.4 .   We are using a parent pom also so i guess there could be some problem with the parent POM file also . I guess i have to do some chenges in parent POM to make it compatible with maven 3 . Due to project security compliance i cant share the complete POM here . Thanx for the help .

Comment: @NitinKhola you 're welcome. You should close this question if there is no more problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [maven-echo-plugin](http://site.supose.org/maven-echo-plugin/):

like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>echo-first-time</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>echo</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <echos>
            <echo>This message is very early in the build process.</echo>
          </echos>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    <execution>
 </plugin>
```